# Firestore data structure to support “querying” overlapping ranges

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

After doing some research on the possibilities Firestore has to offer when it comes to queries, one thing stands out; it does not support queries with range filters on different fields. “And [it] will likely never be available”. 
The most read and frequently suggested solution is to “rethink the data model”.

With that in mind I’m struggling to come up with a working data structure that support “querying” for overlapping ranges. A use-case would be retrieving a list of appointments (with an arbitrary start and end date) for an arbitrary period (like illustrated at the end). The following data structure is what I came up with so far;

For each appointment created, a dates map is stored with all the dates between the start and end date. This way, if we for example query for a given period from 2018-12-25 - 2018-12-26, we perform two separate queries;

```
/appointments
  ...
  {},
 {
  start: "2018-12-24"
  end: "2018-12-27"
  dates : {
    "2018-12-24" : true,
    "2018-12-25" : true,
    "2018-12-26" : true,
    "2018-12-27" : true
  }
 }

collection1 = ...where(.2018-12-25", "==", "true")
collection2 = ...where("2018-12-26", "==", "true")
```

Pros;

- overlapping (as illustrated) appointments by either start or end date (or both) are found
- map with dates is stored on the appointment document itself

Cons;

- the combined collections will contain duplicate documents, they need to be made unique on the client
- as the “query” period becomes bigger, more and more lifting needs to be done, at some point it may be more efficient to retrieve all appointments and do everything client side.

**What other data structure could be used to model such a requirement? (keeping Firestore its querying capabilities in mind)**

```
  requested period:

            |--- period ---|

  included:

          |--a1--|    |--a2--|  
              |----a3----|
        |----------a4----------|

  excluded:

  |-ex1-|                       |-ex2-|
```

Comment: I dug into this for Firebase Realtime Database a few years ago, and yours was pretty much the only solution I could come up with (I'll try to find the question, but it seems buried). I hope somebody else knows a better solution though, as it didn't scale very well for the use-case that I was looking at then (the time slots were more granular than daily).

Comment: Tried some other approaches this weekend, but it did not made things better/easier. Let’s hope the `array-contains` [operator](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/04c9c3aed2428a349f87470c55a904bb5aa57042/packages/firestore/src/core/query.ts#L419) will soon land on the backend, as it is already implemented in the [SDK’s](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/04c9c3aed2428a349f87470c55a904bb5aa57042/packages/firestore/src/core/query.ts#L419)!! Looking forward to it!! You, @FrankvanPuffelen don't happen to know anything about its release... or...?

Comment: All I know is that it's not implemented on the backend yet. The SDKs have it, the backend doesn't (yet).